# Validating services

Tags: php, iphone, android, apache-flex

I am using flex as my front end and would like that only that app is able to communicate with my site/service. Suggest a way to implement this. My main concern as you can see is security.

My backend is php (cakephp/yii/normal php). I do also have mobile apps mainly iPhone and Android and they too will need to be validated by my php.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to identify the user, not the app. If you can ascertain the user who registered the app through regular login, cookies, session, etc. s you need not worry about the client in most cases.

If that doesn't work for you, security through obsurity is the best solution. The typical solution is to include some kind of key in the app that gets sent to the server and can be used to create hash signatures (e.g. HMAC-SHA1) for every request. The drawback of this is that the keys can be distributed easily once cracked.

A harder to crack strategy is to do something obscure, and deny access without notification if the pattern is not matched. E.g. always send obscure request B n seconds after sending request A, where n is the minor version of your client. Use your imagination.